# special characters not supporting in wordpress

Tags: php, database, htmlspecialchars-decode

First I dont know from which thing I am facing problem. I have created a wordpress website and it was working fine. I have moved it later to justhost.com and then I have got this problem. Special characters are not supporting. This is a wordpress website. I dont know coding that much. Please help me.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please share the url..
Also please try to use this function in you content

```
base64_decode($content)
```

It seems that the content is in base64 form and it needs to be decoded..
Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. May I know how to this in the body ? I mean <?php base64_decode($content) ?> like this ? If not how ? Please let me know

Comment: yes like this only but use echo before, if this this did not work you can try to use this <img src="<?php echo  base64_decode($content) ?> ", because it may be an image.. If still you face the problem you can write url here I will solve it for you. Thanks :)

Comment: Thnq so much for this help. :)